# Translating iptables rule to ip6tables

Tags: linux, iptables

What's the equivalent of this iptables rule in ip6tables:

```
-A OUTPUT -s 127.0.0.1/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080
```

I tried this and it doesn't seem to work:

```
-A OUTPUT -s ::1/128 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --on-port 8080
```

Comment: I don't believe output loopback traffic traverses the output table normally, but I could be wrong about that.

Comment: What kernel version? ip6tables supports nat for kernels >= 3.7

Comment: Kernel 2.6.32. Yes I now read that nat is supported form 3.7 and above. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `REDIRECT` target is only available for IPv4.

To redirect IPv6 traffic, you can use `TPROXY` (in very recent versions of netfilter), or use a [userland port forwarding utility](https://serverfault.com/q/252150/126632) such as xinetd.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should use `ip6tables` instead of `iptables` when handling IPv6 traffic; I have not tried though if the standard `iptables` command can handle IPv6.

Comment: Yes that's what I do, using /etc/sysconfig/ip6tables (CentOS)

Comment: Are you sure since you are pasting us the minimal amount of information?

Comment: Yes, seems like ip6tables does not support port redirection. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304342/redirect-a-port-in-ip6tables